# How can I hide a ramdisk from Finder?

Tags: finder, diskutil, hdiutil

I'm creating ramdisks on MacOS following the usual procedure (ie: `diskutil erasevolume HFS+ mydisk` after `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://SIZEINBLOCKS`). They work, but they show up in Finder windows with the usual icon for external drives.

I'm using these ramdisks for development tasks (as disposable drives where I can try builds and easily discard them), so I'd prefer that they don't have a drive unit icon in Finder windows. Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
chflags hidden "/Volumes/RamDisk"
```

And restart your finder with

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: One may also have to manually remove them from under **Devices** on the **Sidebar** in **Finder**.

Comment: It didn't work for me (Sierra 10.12.6). I tried both as user and as root, both with the quotation marks and without, but nothing... (and yes, I restarted Finder)

Comment: This does not remove existing ones from under **Devices** on the **Sidebar** in **Finder**, nor does it stop new ones from appearing on the **Sidebar** in **Finder**.  They will still show on the **Desktop** if hidden files are allowed to show.

Comment: @user3439894 Is it possible to create the ramdisk already hidden from the beginning, rather than trying to hide it afterwards?

Comment: @cesss, There are two setting in **Finder**'s preferences that you could uncheck to not have the **RAM Disks** show, however this also hides all other external disks.  **Finder** > **Preferences** > **General** > **Show these items on the desktop:** > uncheck **External disks** _and_ **Finder** > **Preferences** > **Sidebar** > **Devices** > uncheck **External disks**.